# How can I get data back from an activity as well as Fragments?

Tags: java, android-fragments, android-activity

I have two activities:

- **SetActivity.java**
- **GetActivity.java**

On **SetActivity.java**, I've loaded a fragment Frag1.

I can load Frag2 using a button of Frag1, but as I pressed the back button, I need to get data returned from Frag2 to Frag1 or GetActivity.java to SetActivity.java.

**How can I do this?**

**SetActivity.java** -> Frag1.java(send data) -> Frag2.java(get data) -> Frag1.java(get updated data from Frag2.java)

**SetActivity.java**(set data) -> **GetActivity.java**(get data) -> **SetActivity.java**(Get updated data back)

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use Intents to do that.

You can pass data using `intent.putExtra` in the first fragment and receive it by `intent.getExtra` in the second fragment.

Comment: That's okay, but want that data from the 2nd Activity return in my 1st Activity. How to implement that?

Comment: Then use intent.putExtra in the second fragment and receive it by intent.getExtra in the first fragment....just reverse the fragments to get it !